# How can I set the base category for multiple factor variables to be the most common level in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Let's say that we have a dataframe containing multiple factor variables. We wish to run a regression where each dummy category should represent being in a different group other than that which is most common.

How can we quickly change all the factor variable base categories?

```
library(titanic) # For titanic data
library(tidyverse)

df <- titanic_train %>% tibble()

df <- df %>% mutate(across(c("Sex", "Pclass", "Embarked"), ~as.factor(.x)))
```

We see that the base category is C

```
head(df$Embarked)
#> [1] S C S S S Q
#> Levels:  C Q S
```

This is despite S actually being the most common level

```
table(df$Embarked)
#> 
#>       C   Q   S 
#>   2 168  77 644
```

For `Pclass` we also see that the base category is not the most common factor level:

```
head(df$Pclass)
#> [1] 3 1 3 1 3 3
#> Levels: 1 2 3

table(df$Pclass)
#> 
#>   1   2   3 
#> 216 184 491
```

How can we change both variables to have the most common factor level as the base in one *tidy* line of code?

Answer (score 1):

We can [fct_infreq()](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_inorder.html) function from the forcats package here.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(across(where(is.factor), ~fct_infreq(.x)))
```

This should do the job. Taking another look at the variables from our (very contrived) example above:

```
head(df$Embarked)
#> [1] S C S S S Q
#> Levels: S C Q

table(df$Embarked)
#> 
#>   S   C   Q     
#> 644 168  77   2

head(df$Pclass)
#> [1] 3 1 3 1 3 3
#> Levels: 3 1 2

table(df$Pclass)
#> 
#>   3   1   2 
#> 491 216 184
```

we see that the base category has been changed correctly!